# Animated SVGs in canvg on node.js - how to render/request next frame?

Tags: node.js, animation, svg-animate, node-canvas, canvg

I have a node.js process with a canvas that is being exported to a frame buffer as a bitmap (RGBA values in `Uint8Array`).

Now I want to draw SVG to this canvas, and found `canvg` which works well for static SVG images so far.

But I also need to show animated SVGs. Currently I can only get the first frame of the SVG rendered on the canvas by using v.start() or v.render().

I understand that in a node.js environment we cannot call `requestAnimationFrame()` so that's probably why `canvg` does only render the first frame. It seems to work out of box on the [basic example](https://canvg.js.org/examples/basic) in a browser.

But I'm looking for a way to trigger the rendering again in a node.js process, based on timer or external event, with awareness for the time that has passed since last render, in respect for the animation progress.

```js
  const preset = presets.node({
    DOMParser,
    canvas: Canvas,
    fetch,
  })

  const canvas = preset.createCanvas(width, height)
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d') // TODO: switch to RGB24

  const svgStr = getSVG(t, 'Thank you')
  const v = Canvg.fromString(ctx, svgStr, preset)
  v.start()
 
  async function drawFrame() {

    // I need something here to request the next frame of
    // the animation so it can be drawn on the canvas before
    // the canvas is exported as bitmap.
    // Example of what I need:
    await v.nextFrame(new Date().getMilliseconds())
   
    const renderedImage = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height)
    const buffer = Buffer.from(renderedImage.data)
    em.emit('newFrame', buffer)
  } 

  setInterval(drawFrame, 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Node context has no UI, it's *just* the JS engine (with its own standard library API) so `requestAnimationFrame` would make no sense, there is no graphics context to signal that it has finished drawing a frame and is ready to draw something else now. Instead, you get [process.nextTick()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/process.html#processnexttickcallback-args), which can schedule code to run "when the current synchronous code branch has completed".

For more details, see ["The Node.js Event Loop, Timers, and process.nextTick()"](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) and specifically the [section on process.nextTick() use](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#process-nexttick).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm completely aware that I have no directly connected display that can give me a callback when next frame will be rendered.

That's why I want to use an external event for triggering the renderings, like I did with the `setInterval()` in the bottom. 

The only thing I ask for, is to make cansvg  show the next frame of the animation every time I trigger the rendering of the canvas, so that I can rely on the animation features of SVG.

Comment: Right, and the way you do that is with process.nextTick, not setInterval, and then you check the actual time passed so you can control your frame rate (setInterval makes _no guarantee_ about when it triggers other than "at _least_ X milliseconds later" but if it's half an hour later, that's still 100% spec-compliant). In terms of getting the actual next frame, probably file an issue over on https://github.com/canvg/canvg/issues, since [the API](https://canvg.js.org/api/classes/Canvg) does not appear to have a `next()` or `next(timestamp)`.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating the timer/tick thing in node JS :) 

I guess I'll file an issue at canvg and hope for the best then.